# Error: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC

Tags: java

Alguno me puede dar una mano con eso?

La idea es recuperar todos los objetos "Video", que están guardados en un fichero, pero al parecer solo estoy recuperando el primer objeto y luego me aparece este error: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC .

Dejo una parte el método que, en teoria, debería recuperar dichos obejtos del fichero:

Desde ya muchas gracias.

```
public static void recuperarVideo(Video unVideo) {
    try {ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new 

FileInputStream("F:/JAVA Projectos/taller01/Datos/Videos.txt"));
       Object aux = ois.readObject();
        // Mientras haya objetos
        while (aux!=null)
        {if (aux instanceof Video)
            System.out.println(aux);  // Se escribe en pantalla el objeto
            aux = ois.readObject();
        }   ois.close();}       
catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();}}
```

Método que guarda el objeto "video":

```
 public static void guardarVideo(Video unVideo) {

    try {ObjectOutputStream escribiendoFichero = new ObjectOutputStream(new 
FileOutputStream("F:/JAVA Projectos/taller01/Datos/Videos.txt",true));


        escribiendoFichero.writeObject(unVideo);
        escribiendoFichero.close(); }
     catch (EOFException e) {  return;}
     catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();    }           }
```

Comment: Cuando utilizas [Try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) no hace falta que llames los métodos `close`, ya que éstos se cierran automáticamente al final del código, básicamente estás repitiendo el código dos veces. Te sugiero que evites: `ois.close();` y `escribiendoFichero.close();`

Answer (score 2):

`StreamCorruptedException` se lanza cuando se usa mas de una vez un `ObjectInputStream` o `ObjectOutputStream`.

Remitiendome a tu codigo:

```
  //...
  Object aux = ois.readObject();
  // Mientras haya objetos
  while (aux!=null) {
    if (aux instanceof Video)
      System.out.println(aux);  // Se escribe en pantalla el objeto
      aux = ois.readObject();
  }
  //...
```

La linea que manda la excepción es `aux = ois.readObject();` ocurre una segunda llamada al `ObjectInputStream` allí.

Para de alguna forma tomar esa lista de objetos podrías escribir algo como:

```
videos = (ArrayList <Video>) OIS.readObject();

if(videos != null) {
  for( Video V : videos ) {
    System.out.println(V);
  }
}
```

Espero ayude.

PD.
Como respaldo te dejo este articulo bastante útil acerca de [Leer y Escribir Objetos Java en Archivos](http://www.chuidiang.org/java/ficheros/ObjetosFichero.php)

**Edito:**
Como se trata de usar una lista, al metodo `guardarVideo()` hay que corregirle la manera en que guarda los datos.
La idea es, mejor, serializar una única colección de objetos en vez de serializar/deserializar multiples objetos uno por uno.

Comment: Cabe recalcar que lo que se está leyendo es una `lista de arreglos`, es decir, una lista con uno o muchos objetos de tipo `Video`, así que también se debe escribir una lista. Ya que si se intenta leer una lista, pero lo que se escribió fue **solo un objeto Video**, lanzaría `ClassCastException`

Comment: Y cómo guardarías los datos? Tené presente que esto está siendo usado en una interfaz, por lo tanto puede que no guarde todos los objetos "Video" de una sola vez. Puede que guarde, realicé alguna otra acción e intente guardar nuevamente otro objeto.